# PHP string explode with regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, explode

PHP String explode with regular expression
Example data:

```
"A" 100000  "M" "C" "J"         "JOHNSON TRENCHING" 238910
```

### Expected result:

```
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => '100000',
  2 => 'M',
  3 => 'C',
  4 => '',
  5 => '',
  6 => 'JOHNSON TRENCHING',
  7 => '238910'
);
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Why not just use str_getcsv() with a "\t" separator

Comment: str_getcsv() with a "\t" is not working Expected as mentioned result. please see this link https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55674

Comment: So what was your actual result with str_getcsv()?

Comment: What happens with the J letter?

Comment: The bug you reference was fixed nearly 2 years ago

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$string = '"A" 100000 "M" "C" "J" "JOHNSON TRENCHING" 238910';
$string = preg_match_all('/(\"[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\")|[0-9]+/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: "A"[\s]100000[\s]"M"[\s]"C"[\s]"J"[\s]null[\s]null[\s]"JOHNSON TRENCHING"[\s]238910
i mentioned here [\s] for space.
and i need to add regex to empty string or null value.

Comment: @ramesh What do you mean you need to add regex for an empty string or null? The regex in my code only searches for alphanumeric characters (with whitespace) between double quotes or numeric values without double quotes. If you have extra characters let me know and i'll edit the regex :)

Comment: Sorry Phil it is null value.

Comment: Try this regex instead: `preg_match_all('/(\"[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\")|[0-9]+|[null]+/i', $string, $matches);` I have a